¿Como generar un constructor que inicialice varios campos?
Al momento de generar un constructor solo me deja elegir un campo a inicializar , haciendo que tenga que agregar los demás a mano, vi a mi profesor elegir varios y en la pagina de jet brains también dice que se puede elegir varios. Acaso es una función premium?


click, y control click a todos los subsecuentes

Muchisimas gracias!!!!!

Los IDE no son programas especiales y funcionan igual que el resto de tu sistema operativo. La manera de seleccionar múltiples elementos es usar control + click para ir marcando uno a uno, shift + click para seleccionar un rango o shift + flecha arriba/abajo para extender un rango. Esto es así tanto en intellij como en cualquier carpeta de windows, o en páginas web con dropdowns y en todas las demás partes :)

Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es un problema de programación
